# How to configure update an integration project in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

I've created an integration project in Visual Studio (DWH). I am transferring data from an Oracle database to SQL Server. I need the data to be updated once a day at a certain time without my participation. Does anyone know how such a scheduled download can be configured and where?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can schedule a data transfer between Oracle and MSSQL servers using Windows Task Scheduler. Here are the steps to create a scheduled task:

Open Windows Task Scheduler: You can do this by pressing the Windows key + R and typing "taskschd.msc" in the Run dialog box, or by searching for "Task Scheduler" in the Start menu.

Create a new task: In the Task Scheduler, click on "Create Basic Task" in the right-hand Actions panel.

Give the task a name and description: Enter a name and description for the task, such as "Oracle to MSSQL Data Transfer."

Set the trigger: Click on the "Triggers" tab and then click "New." Choose "Daily" as the recurrence and set the start time to the specific time you want the transfer to occur each day.

Set the action: Click on the "Actions" tab and then click "New." Choose "Start a program" as the action type.
Specify the program to run: In the "Program/script" field, enter the path to the SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) package that you created in Visual Studio. This package should contain the logic for connecting to both databases and transferring the data.

Add arguments: In the "Add arguments" field, enter any command-line arguments that you want to pass to the SSIS package. For example, you might specify the input and output files, or any other configuration settings that you want to use.
Save the task: Click "OK" to save the task.

You can also set up the task to run whether or not a user is logged in, and to run with highest privileges. To do this, go back to the "Triggers" tab, click "Edit," and check the boxes next to "Run whether user is logged on or not" and "Run with highest privileges."

That's it! Your scheduled task should now run automatically every day at the specified time, transferring data from Oracle to MSSQL Server using the SSIS package you created in Visual Studio.